# How to remove newline or 'ENTER" in file by using Unix command

Tags: unix

I am getting input data in file with "|" delimeter but some of records breaking and coming as two records . below is the example ,

for most of description fields data is coming like this only, actually these are entering through web when user press enter while adding comment it going to newline , can you please let me know how to handle this.

I want this record in single line,

```
"2016-03-03 22:26:20|0|I|NOT SET   ||||||||||||||||2015-02-12-04.34.38.734657|2015-02-13| |0|METER FAILURE >30 DAYS"
"           |259000-056608                                          |TRBLRPRT|BDMTRRPL|        ||                                                                      |0|||        "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$yourdata" | tr -d '\r\n'
```

Or

```
cat filename.txt | tr -d '\r\n'
```

To update file:

```
datastr=$(cat filename.txt | tr -d '\r\n')
```

then

```
echo -n "$datastr" > filename.txt
```

Hope it helps

Comment: will it just display the file or replace permanently ?, I want replace it permanently in file , is there any command to do that?

Comment: Thanks it's working , I want to remove the ^M characters also , is that possible ?

Comment: The first step is to load the contents of filename.txt and pipe it to tr where the new line characters and carrage returns are deleted which is then set into the variable datastr.  The second step overwrites the original filename.txt with the modified contents that were generated in the previous step.  There are other programs that will do everything in one step such as sed

Comment: I tried with sed also but not able to achive $ sed -i 's/^M//g' file

Comment: Can you please let me know if you have any other commands to achive this

Comment: the command is removing all newlines( i mean at the end of the record also) and merging all the records as singal record.
is there any way to remove in betwee new lines characters of new line.

Comment: @SanthoshKancherla you can pipe $datastr to sed -e "s/^M//g" or sed -e "s/^M//" to remove the ^M chars. As for all the records, write a script that loops over each file and runs the above commands. Instead of echo -n $datastr > filename.txt use the append operator to append each record to the singular record file like so echo $datastr >> records.txt. Notice it is echo not echo -n in this method

Answer (score 0):

This substitutes a space for carriage returns or line feeds

```
cat test.txt | tr  ["\n","\r"] ' '
```